# How often are moderator elections held?

Tags: support, election

I was wondering, with the current elections underway, how often does Gaming.SE hold these elections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, we hold elections once shortly after graduation, then roughly look into it once a year afterwards. However, this is further refined based on the needs of the site. For example, if the current set of moderators (after this election) is more than sufficient, then we could probably skip a year of elections. Times change and the important thing is to have people who have the available time to spend on the site and cover it well. As such, a lot of elections is about when the site needs it, more than it is any periodic effect. Periodic checks are more as a good habit to investigate whether there is an unspoken need.

In this scenario, we're hosting a second set of elections because I, a former elected moderator, got [hired by Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/welcome-valued-associate-chris-jaeger/). Since I'll no longer be able to dedicate full attention to this site as in the past, and because traffic has increased and we're expecting some time table changes, [we're going for two new moderators to supplement badp and Juan](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/a-little-birdie-whispered-to-me-an-awful-lot-of-little-birdies-shaped-like-site).